# how to implement Dropdownlist list image selection as well as textbox in MVC4 RazorView

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

Hi all I have to implement one Dropdownlist which contains the image with country code and one textbox associated with that i am sharing you all the below screenshot which i want to Implement in my Form with MVC4+Razor View any help will be appreciated.I want one Mobile No field which i want to save in my form

[image]

Can some one please share some sample code so that i can implement and also i have to save the values through form

Comment: Please share what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a textbox with auto complete feature enabled on that. You can use any autocomplete plugin like jQuery UI library autocomplete to achieve this.jQuery ui allows you to customize the autocomplete option item's HTML markup to include the image.

The first step is to load the ***jQuery***, ***jQuery UI*** libraries to your page.

Next, In our view, we need a textbox where we need this feature.

```
<input id="countrySearch" value="" />
```

Next step is to write an action method in your controller which returns the data you want in JSON format.

```
public ActionResult Countries(string term)
{
   var list=new List<CountryVM>();
   // Hardcoding 2 items for demo.
   //to do : read data from your db and build the list.

   list.Add(new CountryVM { ID=1,Name="US",FlagImg="http://yoursite/usa.jpg"});
   list.Add(new CountryVM { ID=2,Name="IN",FlagImg="http://yoursite/in.jpg"});

   return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Assuming you have a viewmodel called `CountryVM` like

```
public class CountryVM
{
  public int ID { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public string FlagImg { set;get;}
}
```

So this action method will return JSON data like this.

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Name": "US",
        "FlagImg": "http://yoursite/usa.jpg"
    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Name": "US",
        "FlagImg": "http://yoursite/in.jpg"
    }
]
```

Let's go back to client side, In out view we have our textbox, now we need to enable autocomplete plugin on that textbox. By default, the plugin will render a listitem(`<li>`) in the auto suggest dropdown. We need to tell the plugin to build our customized markup (Which includes the flag image) instead. We can use the `create` method to do the customization we want. So have this javascript code to do that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){

    $("#countrySearch").autocomplete({       
        source: function (request, response) {                  
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Countries","Home")",                    
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {                   
                        return { label: item.Name, value: item.ID,
                                                   image: item.FlagImg };
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        create: function () {
            $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $('<li>')
                    .append("<a><div><img src='" +item.image+ "' />"
                                                 +item.label+"</div></a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {   
            //you can access ui.item to get the selected item object.        
            console.log("Selected item id : " + ui.item.value);
            return false;
        }
    });

 });
</script>
```

That's it. This should give you the autocomplete feature with images inside that.

Comment: Can you please share some example as i am new to MVC and Jquery or your can guide me so that i can implement

Comment: @Rahul I updated the answer with a complete working solution.

Comment: Thanks I have implemented by taking help from your code and I am able to get this but only one problem I am facing I am not getting the icon images I am getting the dropdown but images are not coming

Comment: @Rahul Did you give the absolute url ? Using firebug check what value you are getting and make sure you have an image exists in that url

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, `dropdown` and `textbox` are different and are aligned next to each other. Depending on `dropdown` item selection `textbox` value is changed.

For having image for dropdown check following link

http://fairwaytech.com/2012/08/adding-images-select-lists-mvc3/

Comment: I am not able to implement can you please share some sample code