# Auto-complete in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a textbox when i enter something in e.g. a staff name it should look it up into the database and display a staff picture and its fist and second name. How would i do that, I have seen some of the post on-line but i dont understand the concept of where jquery is getting its data(url). this is what i have done.

```
<p>   
@Html.TextBox("", new { id="staff" })
</p>
```

This is my jquery, i have literally copied and changed few things around from one of the online answer, some of the things in here might not need it so feel free to edit:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#staff").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.getJSON("/Forums/Ajax/GetTags", { term: request.term }, function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (el) {
                    return {
                        label: el.TagName,
                        value: el.TagId
                    };
                }));
            });
        },

    });
});
```

This is how my model looks like:

```
    public string ID{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string Picture{ get; set; }
```

Now how would i pass my model to the controller and controller to my javascript, and also i would like to have a placeholder in my textbox saying "Please Enter Staff Name". 
Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: This answers explains what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22115032/40521

Answer (score 0):

First, let's start with the place holder

```
 <p>   
     @Html.TextBox("staff", new {value="Please Enter Staff Name" })
</p>
```

Your action may look like this

```
  public ActionResult GetTags(string term){
  var terms=from entry in db.Entities where entry.name.StartWith(term) 
            select new new MyModel(){
                             ID=entry.ID,
                             Name =entry.Name,
                             SecondName =entry.SecondName ,
                             Picture=entry.Picture

                           }
  return Json(terms,"text/json",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Your jQuery may look like this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#staff").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {

        $.getJSON("/Forums/Ajax/GetTags", { term: request.term }, function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (el) {
                return {
                    label: el.Name,
                    value: el.ID,
                    SecondName: el.SecondName,
                    Name=el.Name/*, SO ON*/
                };
            }));
        });
    },
     create: function () {
        $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (list, item) {
            return $('<li>')
                .append("<a><div><img src='" +item.Picture+ "' />"
                                             +item.Name+" "+item.SecondName+"</div></a>")
                .appendTo(list);
        };
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {   
       alert("Selected item id : " + ui.item.SecondName);
        return false;//dont follow the link
    }

   });
});
```

Hope It will help you.